# Actively rotate a SKSpriteNode when swiping?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, skspritenode

I want to rotate a `SKSpriteNode`, if the user swipes to the left or to the right.
Could I use an `UIGestureRecognizer` or is there another way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is adding two UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the SKView (one for each direction).

If you want to handle more slow finger movements, you will need to substitute them by a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)  And how should I rotate the SKSpriteNode when calling with the GestureRecognizer ?

Answer (score 0):

Within your scene, implement `didMoveToView:(SKView*)view` like so

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe)];
    self.leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:self.leftSwipeRecognizer];

    self.rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipe)];
    self.rightSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:self.rightSwipeRecognizer];
}

- (void)rightSwipe {

    //whatever angle and duration you need here  (angle in radians)
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    CGFloat angle = 0;

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:nodeIdentifier usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:angle duration:duration]];
    }];
}
```

- the node must be set as a child of your scene.
- the nodeIdentifier here will be what ever the name is of the node you want to rotate. This should be set as the `name` property of the `SKSpriteNode` which you wish to move.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! The only problem is, the node doesn't rotate on its own axis and not in real time with the users swipe...

Comment: Another approach would be to animate the sprite via an SKTextureAtlas, then using the class method on SKAction, animateWithTextures:duration: